# How to check the position of taskbar in windows in win32 program?

Tags: winapi

I'm writing a small application in Windows using win32(vc++) and I want to create a different view based on the position of the taskbar. How can I check the position of taskbar in code like any api?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`SHAppBarMessage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762108(v=vs.85).aspx) function with the [`ABM_GETTASKBARPOS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787949(v=vs.85).aspx) message.

Comment: What about when the taskbar is spread across multiple displays?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No idea to be honest, it wouldn't surprise me if this is another API they've "forgotten" to update in the same vein as Aero Snap.

Comment: It looks like I should not have tried to be clever though, judging by the voting. Ho hum.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Wasn't me :)

Comment: No, I did not think it was! And anyway, everyone has a perfect right to vote how they please.

Answer (score 1):

The taskbar may be displayed on multiple displays so in general it's not possible to retrieve a single rect that defines it's position. It may occupy discontiguous space.

Use `EnumDisplayMonitors` to enumerate the attached displays. Then for each display use `GetMonitorInfo` to obtain bounding and work area rectangles for the display. If there's a difference, then that difference is (usually) due to the taskbar. Remember that the taskbar can appear on multiple displays.

I say usually because you might have applications with app bars that reduce the working area. But I'm guessing that what you really want to do is display your program so that it does not overlap with the taskbar, and if you want to avoid overlapping the taskbar then you'll likely want to avoid overlapping app bars too.

Comment: That's a bit kludgy, and as you've suggested there's no guarantee the difference is due to the taskbar. May as well enum for the window class and just use GetWindowRect.

Comment: im looking for somthing simple as taskbar.position like api would give me left, roght ,bottom or top

Comment: @TumuluriVDattaVamshi Do you appreciate the subtleties of multiple monitor systems and a taskbar that appears on multiple monitors? Given that subtlety, what you are looking for is quite clearly impossible.

Comment: I think what you are asking is extrenious to the topic.

Comment: You might not care about multi-monitor systems, but I'm at a system right now where what you are asking for is not possible. If you don't care, just do what Jonathan says.

Comment: im not using winforms, im using win32 api. and im a beginner

Comment: Your question is tagged `winforms`. Which is described like this: *WinForms is the informal name given to Windows Forms, a GUI class library in the Microsoft .NET Framework, which provides a user interface for programs designed to run on Windows machines.* So, I guess you need to remove that tag.

Comment: Anyway, I fixed your question. Please not carefully the edits I made and in future be more careful with your use of tags.