# How can I set modal position to bottom left corner of screen?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, modal-dialog

I'm using WinApi and C++ and I'm trying to set a modal's position to the bottom left corner of the screen but I don't know how. I want this program to work for different screen resolutions and to take into consideration the taskbar (the modal has to be right above it).
I currently set the window position using this:

```
SetWindowPos( GetHwnd(), HWND_TOPMOST, 0,0,0,0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE );
```

Comment: *"Bottom left"* of which screen? Did you consider the taskbar not being at the bottom at all? What does *"modal"* mean to you anyway. It's not obvious to me at all.

Comment: I didn't realise there were so many things to take into consideration. Let's say the left side of the main screen (not bottom necessarily). By modal I mean a modal dialog pop-up.

Comment: A modal window needs an owner, so modal to which owner?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. This is how I create the window: m_hWnd = CreateWindowEx( m_styleex, m_classname, nullptr, m_style, 0, 0, 0, 0, m_parentWnd, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr );

Comment: That piece of code is ambiguous. The value of `m_style` controls, whether `m_parentWnd` is the parent or [owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-features#owned-windows). Modality is not a feature of a window; it is the result of code logic, when a popup window is displayed. The standard implementation for modality is to disable the owner of a modal window.

Comment: m_style has the following value: WS_POPUP | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN;

Comment: Related: [How to check the position of taskbar in windows in win32 program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31135157/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [MonitorFromWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-monitorfromwindow) to retrieve a handle to the monitor that the window is displayed on.

Then use [GetMonitorInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmonitorinfoa) to get the [MONITORINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagmonitorinfo) of that monitor.

In the MONITORINFO you will find the `RECT rcWork` which describes the working area, i.e. excluding the taskbar, whereever it may be.

Find out the size of your window with [GetWindowRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect) and place it in the bottom-left corner of `rcWork`.

Note that you should in this case not use `SWP_NOMOVE` [because this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos)

> Retains the current position (ignores X and Y parameters).